# solving a system of equations (3 equations, 3 variables)

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I have 3 equations and 3 unknown variables as follows

$$\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}x=y^{\alpha-1}-z$$

$$\left(1+\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}\right)x=\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\alpha y-\rho\right)$$

$$x\left(\frac{(1-\sigma)\beta}{1-\alpha}+\beta\frac{y^{\alpha}}{\phi z}\right)=\rho$$

Where $x,y,z$ are unknown variables and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\rho$, $\phi$, $\sigma$ are known constant parameters.

Whatever I have tried, I could not find an analytical result for these three variables.

What possible methods could be used to solve this system ? Numerical methods or any other methods ?

Thanks in advance for hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will derive an equation which contains only $$y$$:
from (2) we get
 $$x={\frac { \left( \alpha\,y-\rho \right)  \left( \alpha-1 \right) }{
\sigma\, \left( \alpha-\beta-1 \right) }}
$$
plugging this in (1)
$${\frac { \left( \alpha\,y-\rho \right)  \left( \alpha-1 \right) }{
\sigma\, \left( \alpha-\beta-1 \right) } \left( {\frac { \left( 1-
\sigma \right) \beta}{1-\alpha}}+{\frac {\beta\,{y}^{\alpha}}{\Phi\,z}
} \right) }=\rho$$

from (3) we obtain
 $$z={\frac {{y}^{\alpha-1}\alpha+x\beta-{y}^{\alpha-1}}{\alpha-1}}$$
with this equation we obatin one equation only in $$y$$ namely
$${\frac { \left( \alpha\,y-\rho \right)  \left( \alpha-1 \right) }{
\sigma\, \left( \alpha-\beta-1 \right) } \left( {\frac { \left( 1-
\sigma \right) \beta}{1-\alpha}}+{\frac {\beta\,{y}^{\alpha} \left( 
\alpha-1 \right) }{\Phi\, \left( {y}^{\alpha-1}\alpha+x\beta-{y}^{
\alpha-1} \right) }} \right) }=\rho
$$
where 
$$x={\frac { \left( \alpha\,y-\rho \right)  \left( \alpha-1 \right) }{
\sigma\, \left( \alpha-\beta-1 \right) }}
$$

Comment: This is very helpful thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In the particular case of this problem, you could notice that the equations only involve $x$ and $z$ by themselves (and not any power of them). So, the idea is to eliminate $x$ and $y$ expressing them as function of the left variable $y$ which appears with some exponents.

Since you can eliminate two variables among three, you are then left with one equation in $y$. This is what Dr. Sonnhard Graubner did.

Now, for sure, you are left with a possibly rather complex equation in $y$ which probably will not show any explicit solutions; so, numerical methods will probably be required but it is always easier to work a single nonlinear equation than the original system of equations.

**Edit**

Taking into account your last comment, I suspect that you tried to write a single equation in $y$. Since it is quite complex, I suggest you to define the pieces $x(y)$ and $z(y)$ and write the final equation accordingly as $$x(y)=\frac{(\alpha -1) }{\sigma  (\alpha -\beta -1)}(\alpha  y-\rho )$$ $$z(y)=\frac{\beta  }{\alpha -1}x(y)+y^{\alpha -1}$$ $$F(y)=x(y) \left(\frac{\beta  (1-\sigma )}{1-\alpha }+\frac{\beta\, y^{\alpha }}{z(y)\, \phi
   }\right)-\rho=0$$

Using your numbers, as I already commented, I found a single solution $$\{x= 0.219565,y= 1.572257,z=0.697140\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I try to solve $y$ numerically, I find some results with complex numbers, which I think is due to the powers on $y$.

Comment: you can send me a number example and i will also try to solve it numerically

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I use the following calibration for constant parameters ;
$\sigma=1.8$, $\alpha=0.3$, $\beta=0.1$ $\rho=0.02$ and $\phi=0.8$
I have tried on Mathematica but I always get some complex numbers. What do you think about it ?

Comment: @optimalcontrol. I used your numbers and found $x=0.219565$, $y=1.57226$, $z=0.697140$ which is the unique solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks you so much. I have found also the correct unique solution for the system.

Thanks to you, I have found out that I was using the inappropriate command on Mathematica. As you have said on your edit, I was trying to solve the only one equation with y because Mathematica was failing to process the three dimensional equation system.

Comment: @optimalcontrol. Glad it helped ! I am surprized that Mathematica was failing to process the three dimensional equation system. Could you e-mail to me your Mathematica code (you will find my address in my profile) ?